# How to find Dependent Components for a Class/Page/Trigger using API (Tooling or Metadata API)?

Tags: salesforce

We are trying to automate certail processes for which we need to find the dependent components for a Class/Page/Trigger.

We understand that salesforce is providing dependent components using "Show Dependencies" button when respective components are viewed but is there a way to get these programatically?

Any details around this is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SymbolTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_symboltable.htm) that is exposed via the Tooling API. In particular, look at the `externalReferences` field.

> Contains the name, namespace, and external class, method and variable references for the Apex class or trigger. These references can be used for symbol highlighting or code navigation.

If the SymbolTable isn't available for the ApexClass you will need to force a compile first. See [Trying to get SymbolTable of an Apex class and get null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/57406/102).

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.